# ¿Por qué la función recursiva en python me devuelve un valor mas del que debería?

Tags: python, funciones

El programa consiste en solicitar ingresar por teclado un valor para la variable "A" y un valor para la variable "B", estos deben ser diferentes a 0, y luego obtener el el producto entre A y B  mediante el uso de una función recursiva.
Por ejemplo: A=3 y B=5 -> 3*5 = 3+3+3+3+3 = 15
El problema esta en que me esta devolviendo un siempre 1 valor mas del que debieria, por ejemplo: 3*5=16
La función la plantee de la siguiente manera

```
def Multiplicacion(A,B):
    
    if B!=0:
        return A + Multiplicacion(A,B-1)
    else:
        return 1
```

La llamada a la función:

```
print(Multiplicacion(3,5))
```

Comment: Porqué devuelves 1 si B es 0? debería ser A*0 = 0, con lo que se soluciona tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El return del Else te esta sumando una unidad al final
por lo que tu código debería quedar igual, sólo cambiar el return del else a 0

```
def Multiplicacion(A,B):
    
    if B!=0:
        return A + Multiplicacion(A,B-1)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: He probado el código y el resultado es el esperado. Ademas si haces Multiplicar(3,0) te daría 1. Por lo que no es valido. En la funcion estas sumando 
    return A + Multiplicacion(A,B-1) siempre que B no sea 1. Pero si B es 1 multiplica por 0 y te devuelve 1

Comment: Multiplicar(1,0) se iria al else y devuelve 0. Ese caso se da cuando B vale 1